# How to convert csv file to dictionary so that top row is keys, and columns (in list form) are values (without numpy.loadtxt and panda)?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

(To preface, I know/believe you could use numpy.loadtxt and pandas but I want to know how to achieve the same result without them.)

I would have a csv file like this, after opening it and assigning it to file while also using splitlines():

```
file = 
'Top1','Top2','Top3','Top4','Top5'
'1','a','3','b','5'
'a','2','b','3','c'
'1','a','3','b','5'
```

How could I go about converting the file into a dictionary, with the top row being the keys,
and the column underneath each key being its value, like so:

```
a_dict = {
'top1': ['1', 'a', '1'],
'top2': ['a', '2', 'a'],
'top3': ['3', 'b', '3'],
'top4': ['b', '3', 'b'],
'top5': ['5', 'c', '5']
}
```

I tried by doing this first:

```
a_dict = {}
for i in file[0].split(','):
    a_dict[i] = ''
print(a_dict)
```

which gave me:

```
a_dict = {"'top1'": '', "'top2'": '', "'top3'": '', "'top4'": '', "'top5'": ''}
```

then, to get the columns into lists I tried:

```
prac_list = []
for i in file[1:]:
    i = i.split(',')
    x = 0
    prac_list.append(num[x])
    x+=1
print (prac_list)
```

and that gave me:

```
prac_list = ["'1'", "'a'", "'1'"]
```

but I got stuck up to that point, the idea was to have the `for loop` go through elements below the first row, and have it so each loop iteration would take the `x`'th index of each row and append them together as one element in the list like `['1', 'a', '1']`. eg:

```
x = 0
for i in file[1:]:
    get x'th index of each row
    append together as one element in prac_list
    x += 1
print (prac_list)
```

then loop through the dict and change the values to the items in the list, but I believe I am messing up the slicing and the appending to the list part.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `zip`,

```
text = """'Top1','Top2','Top3','Top4','Top5'
'1','a','3','b','5'
'a','2','b','3','c'
'1','a','3','b','5'""" 
lines = text.split('\n') # This equals to the file_pointer.readlines()

keys = keys = list(map(lambda x:x.replace("'", '').lower(), lines[0].split(',')))
values = [list(map(lambda x:x.replace("'", ''), line.split(','))) for line in lines[1:]]
result = dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Output:

```
{'top1': ['1', 'a', '3', 'b', '5'],
 'top2': ['a', '2', 'b', '3', 'c'],
 'top3': ['1', 'a', '3', 'b', '5']}
```

Comment: the output for the values is the rows, I was wondering how to do the same but with the values being the columns.

Comment: If values are in a column, you can simply iterate through the lines and split the line taking the first element as the key and the rest are values. And update the result in the ityeration.

Comment: Apologies if I'm not understanding you correctly but, in your solution, the output produces a dict where the values of each key is a row of the data from the file. I'm wanting it so that it takes the same data from the file, but instead of the values being the rows from the file, the values would be the columns. Like in your output, it only has 3 keys, where I'm looking for all 5 keys

Answer (score 1):

I think this code will help you :

```
with open('Book1.csv','r')as f:
    file=f.read().splitlines()

a_dict ={i.replace("'",""):[] for i in file[0].split(',')}

prac_list = []
for i in file[1:]:
    i = i.split(',')
    x=0
    for j in a_dict:
        a_dict[j].append(i[x].replace("'",""))
        x+=1
print(a_dict)
```

> **Output**

```
{'Top1': ['1', 'a', '1'], 'Top2': ['a', '2', 'a'], 'Top3': ['3', 'b', '3'], 'Top4': ['b', '3', 'b'], 'Top5': ['5', 'c', '5']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csv` library to iterate through rows:

```py
import csv


with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader_obj = csv.DictReader(f)
    
    data = next(reader_obj)
    for row in reader_obj:
        data = {k: (data[k]+[v] if type(data[k]) is list else [data[k]]+[v]) for k,v in row.items()}

print(data)
```

```
{"'Top1'": ["'1'", "'a'", "'1'"], "'Top2'": ["'a'", "'2'", "'a'"], "'Top3'": ["'3'", "'b'", "'3'"], "'Top4'": ["'b'", "'3'", "'b'"], "'Top5'": ["'5'", "'c'", "'5'"]}
```